# 3D models of the unfoldings of the hypercube?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, polyhedra

There are (apparently) 261 distinct unfoldings of the 4D hypercube, a.k.a., the
tesseract, into 3D.<sup>1</sup>
These unfoldings (or "nets") are analogous to the 11 unfoldings of
the 3D cube into the plane.<sup>2</sup>
Usually only one hypercube unfolding is illustrated,

---

[image: TesseractUnf]

         
<sup>(Image from [this link](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/hypercube.htm).)</sup>

---

the one made famous in 
Salvador Dali's painting
*[Corpus Hypercubus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucifixion_(Corpus_Hypercubus))*.
My question is:

> ***Q***. Has anyone made models/images of the 261 unfoldings as solid objects in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

(If not, I might do so myself.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Peter Terney, "Unfolding the Tesseract."
*Journal of Recreational Mathematics*, Vol. 17(1), 1984-85.

---

<sup>2</sup>

[image: CubeNets]

---

**Update**. See also the followup question, "[Which unfoldings of the hypercube tile 3-space: How to check for isometric space-fillers?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/199097/6094)."

Comment: An unusual question in that I am kinda hoping no one answers.

Comment: How does this compare with the (polycube version of the) octomino count?  It might be easier to list those which are not unfoldings of the tesseract.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: I don't understand the phrase "the (polycube version of the) octomino count."

Comment: You might like a movie on the 2D case:  http://www.etudes.ru/ru/etudes/cubisme/

Comment: @Joseph: what would be the benefit of having such models? Along with additional information, like the properties of the cube's face-adjacency graph or usability in architecture, a complete set of such 3D unfoldings could however be of broader interest.

Comment: "Domino's Sugar?  I'd like to place an order for $2088$ sugar cubes..."

Comment: octominoes are like pentominoes, but composed of 8 squares instead of five.  I'm suggesting that connected arrangements of 8 cubes are not much more numerous than unfoldings of a tesseract.  But I don't know.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: Oh, I see. There are 369 planar "free" octominoes. Haven't yet found a count in 3D.

Comment: @ManfredWeis: That is a legitimate question, but I would prefer not to answer it.

Comment: I notice that of the 11 unfoldings of the cube, 2 have mirror symmetries and the other 9 do not.  If we count the "chiral" pairs separately, then we have a total of 20 unfoldings.

From the beautiful figures in two of the answers, it is difficult for me to tell how many of the 261 unfoldings of the 4D hypercube have mirror symmetries.  Does someone know?

Comment: Re the number of free octacubes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycube says it is 3811. So really it is quite unlikely for an octacube to be a net of a hypercube.

Comment: Oh, so we have a sequence [1, 11, 261, ...](https://oeis.org/A091159)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: See [Number of hypercube unfoldings](https://mathoverflow.net/q/300713/6094).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I implemented the ideas in the paper using Mathematica.  I pushed it a bit further to actually generate the images below.  You can [download this Mathematica notebook](https://www.marksmath.org/UnfoldingTheTesseract.nb) to see the code and detailed explanation.

You might notice Dali's original in the middle of the third row from the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Please share the code, *Yes*! :-) Do you verify the count 261?

Comment: Yes, it's 261.  I did the cube with similar techniques and got 11 as well.  I need to clean up the notebook just a bit and I'm not sure what the correct way to share it is.  It's quite a lot of code that's probably not completely appropriate for this site.  I could upload the notebook to my webspace and just post a link, if nothing else.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, a link is best. And, sure, clean up as you wish. This is great! Were Dali still with us, he'd have 260 new paintings to contemplate. :-)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke The linked notebook is there now - hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 15):

I used [sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) to make a [3d animation of all 261 unfoldings](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/moritz/mo/198722/unfoldings).

Here is a screenshot of the first few:

[image]

The file [cube-unfoldings.txt](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/moritz/mo/198722/cube-unfoldings.txt) contains all the unfoldings, each line contains a list of 8 points.

**Edit**: By popular, I add the (poorly commented) code:

[unfolding the hypercube.ipynb](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/moritz/mo/198722/unfolding%20the%20hypercube.ipynb): a jupyter notebook with sage code to generate the pairings for the unfoldings together and find the embeddings.
To view the code easily, checkout the [file at github](https://github.com/mo271/mo271.github.io/blob/master/mo/198722/unfolding%20the%20hypercube.ipynb)

The animation on the website is made with [threejs](http://threejs.org), and all the code is contained in the [unfoldings.html](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/moritz/mo/198722/unfoldings.html), which you can also [view on github](https://github.com/mo271/mo271.github.io/blob/master/mo/198722/unfoldings.html).

Comment: Beautiful! ${}$

Comment: Very nice! I had the idea of displaying these on the web using X3Ddom on my extended to do list - I guess I can cross that off my list. :) Can you make the code available?

Comment: @MarkMcClure: thanks! And sure: do you want the code for the animation or the generation of the unfoldings. (the latter is sage, the former threejs)

Comment: @MoritzFirsching why not both? :)

Comment: @MarkMcClure done!

Comment: @MoritzFirsching I was specifically interested in the Sage code, as the JS is nicely contained in the webpage. Am I correct in thinking that the variable `allboxes` at line 240 of the webpage specifies the locations of the cubes and was generated by Sage and that you wrote the the rest of the Javascript was specifically to interpret and render the boxes?

Comment: @j.c. sure, I didn't mean 'or' to be exclusive..

Comment: @MarkMcClure exactly. In the link for the source of the website its line 165, though..

Comment: @MoritzFirsching Thanks! I think the code improves the answer a lot.